# Moved lib.so.6 file and now system not loading

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, debian-cd

I didn't do the cleverest thing and thought it may work.
I wanted to use steam on kali 64 bit and after the installation when i tried to launch the application it popped up an error saying 32 bit system lib.so.6 file not found. But it was there in 64 bit lib folder so i moved the file instead of copying to 32 bit lib folder and now my system isn't booting up.
Pls help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from your favorite live CD
2. Mount your root partition
3. Move the library back into the correct place
4. Reboot